# Is it possible to read and load the excel(xlsx) file in Azure Blob container using Snowflake SnowPark?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, snowflake-schema

I've multiple XLSX files in the azure blob container which I should load those
xlsx files snowflake table.

**Note:** I don't want to perform the conversion operation of xlsx to csv which actually
consumes more time. Also I did used the ADF Copy Activity for loading but it is taking more time to load the data.

so is there any way I can use the snowflake snowpark to load the xlsx to the snowflake table?

Additionally, I welcome any other feasible alternatives for this issue through which I can load the xlsx data quickly into the snowflake

Comment: You can use pyspark to load the excel file from blob as dataframe and write to snowflake table as an alternative.

Comment: You can use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to create a Dataframe which you can save later to Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

> Additionally, I welcome any other feasible alternatives for this issue through which I can load the xlsx data quickly into the snowflake

You can try databricks with pandas dataframe here. First Mount the Blob Storage to databricks and read the excel file using `openpyxl`. Write the pandas dataframe  to snowflake as suggested by **@Sergiu**.

```
import pandas as pd

storage_account_name = "storage account name"
container_name = "container name"
mount_point = "/mnt/mount point"
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source=f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point=mount_point,
  extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net": "storage account access key"
  }
)
```

[image]
install `openpyxl` if you don't have.
`!pip install openpyxl`

**Reading excel file after mounting:**

```
file_path = f"/dbfs/{mount_point}/myexcel.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,engine="openpyxl")
```

[image]

After reading it as pandas dataframe, follow this [procedure](https://stephenallwright.com/write-to-snowflake-from-pandas-dataframe/) by **@stephenallwright** to write this dataframe to snowflake table.